# C# Excel SaveAs issue

Tags: c#, excel

Hi I am using following c# code to write excel workbook from a web application and the tried to save the excel in my machine.

```
Excel._Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
string excelFile = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/ExcelTemplate/Sample.xlsx");
Excel._Workbook workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add(excelFile);
Excel._Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Sheets["Analytics"] as Excel.Worksheet;
Excel.Range cells = worksheet.Cells;

cells[1, 1].Value = "Details Between " + StartDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") + " & " + EndDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
cells[18, 1].Value = "Response Details Between " + StartDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") + " & " + EndDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
cells[1, 8].Value = "Detailed Response Between " + StartDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") + " & " + EndDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");

workbook.SaveAs(@"C:\ExportedSheet.xlsx", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
               Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlUserResolution, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);


workbook.Close();
```

every time the SaveAs method throws an exception, saying cannot access "ExportedSheet.xlsx". I am not able to find any fix for this, please help me to fix the issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check that the file isn't read-only. Or that it exists in that path.

Comment: Is this a UAC (User Account Control) issue - WIndows 7 upwards - and you do not have sufficient privilege to save files in the root directory.

Comment: thanks @Thanos, but i want user to select path of this exported sheet in his/her machine.

Comment: If it is a UAC problem - then the user will need to select a location they have access rights to - or possibly running "As Administrator" (if possible) will allow them to select that location.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing the exact error will help in solving this problem. Since you have not mentioned the error you notice, try the following steps. If this does not help, place the code in a try-catch block. Print the error message after the exception is caught. Open the excel workbook and uncheck the option that is causing this error. Save the workbook and execute the code.

1. Open the excel file - C:\ExportedSheet.xlsx

   > > Go to - File -> Options -> Trust Ceneter -> Trust Center Settings -> Privacy Options. Under Document specific options, uncheck remove personal information on file properties on save. 
   > >     Save the excel file. Execute the code.
2. Open the excel file - C:\ExportedSheet.xlsx

   > > Click on Review tab. Under Share Workbook->Editing option, uncheck - Allow changes by more than one user at the same time. This also allows work book merging. 
   > >     Save the excel file. Execute the code.

   try
   {
      //code
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
      //print the error - ex.Message
   }